# Java / MySQL null pointer exception halfway through resultset

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception, resultset

I have a java based epos system in use within my company and am presently writing a series of Java apps for use in the back office / warehouse. The purpose of my current project is to extract an Image (saved as a blob), and a title (varchar value) from MYSQL and display each of these on JLabels within a JPanel.

First the sql query is handled within a class called DataLogic like so:

```
public class DataLogic {

MySQLConnect mysqlConnect = new MySQLConnect();
private Connection connect = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

public ResultSet getCategories(){
    try {
 connect = mysqlConnect.connDatabase();    
 preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT image, name, texttip from CATEGORIES ORDER BY name");
 ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    return resultSet;
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

AS you can see the get Categories function returns a ResultSet which is used in the populateCats() function of a class called GuiEvents, the relevant section of which is below:

```
public void populateCats(){
    results = dataLogic.getCategories();
    try{
        int count = 0;
        while (results.next()) {
            ++count;   // Get data from the current row and use it
        } 
        results.first();
        while (results.next()){
            GridLayout catLayout = new GridLayout(count,2);
            System.out.println(count);
            gui.catList.setLayout(catLayout);
            JLabel catLabel = new JLabel(results.getString(2));
            JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel();
            imgLabel.setIcon(displayImage(results.getBytes(1)));
            gui.catList.add(imgLabel);
            gui.catList.add(catLabel);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ImageIcon displayImage(byte[] bytes) {
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(bytes);

// new code
int imgHeight = img.getHeight(null);
int imgWidth = img.getWidth(null);
int newHeight = imgHeight / 2;
int newWidth = imgWidth / 2;
//System.out.println(imgHeight + "," + imgWidth);
Image resizedImg = img.getScaledInstance(40,40,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH );
//end new code

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImg);
return icon;
}
```

My problem is that although it compiles and runs i get the following error within netbeans:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Toolkit.createImage(Toolkit.java:1111)
    at gapricing.app.first.GuiEvents.displayImage(GuiEvents.java:48)
    at gapricing.app.first.GuiEvents.populateCats(GuiEvents.java:39)
    at gapricing.app.first.Gui.<init>(Gui.java:111)
    at gapricing.app.first.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

and whilst 29 of the images and titles are displayed exactly as I would have liked the remianing 9 do not although thanks to the gridlayout 9 empty boxes are included at the bottom of the JPanel.
Can anyone help pls??

Comment: It looks like `bytes` might be null.

Comment: agree that bytes are null. Try to add 'WHERE image IS NOT NULL' to your SQL and see it helps

Comment: thanks guys yes an image was missing from db.

Answer (score 1):

thanks guys yes an image was missing from db.
Simple edit:

```
if (results.getBytes(1) != null){
imgLabel.setIcon(displayImage(results.getBytes(1)));
}
```

If bytes are null it just dispalys an empty label. Thanks alot